# Can't order custom objects in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I set up CoreData with CloudKit and managed to create an entity with a transformable attribute. The attribute has a custom class (Item) which I created. It contains an Int and some other stuff that is not important atm.
I setup the basic CRUD function successfully. Everything works perfectly. My only problem seems to be that I can't order my items. I followed some tutorials but it just doesn't work.

What I want to do is having the objects I save being ordered based on their index.

This is what I'm doing:

- In my NsManagedObject subclass I declared this function:

```swift
 static func getListItemFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MyObject>{
        let request = MyObject.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<MyObject>
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "item", ascending: true)]
        return request
    }
```

- In my PersistentManager class I did:

```swift
class PersistentManager {
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreDataShar")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        //forse
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("No Descriptions found")
        }
        description.setOption(true as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        
       
        //forse
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.processUpdate), name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil)
        
        return container
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    
    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    func processUpdate(notification: NSNotification) {
        operationQueue.addOperation {
            // get our context
            let context = self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
            context.performAndWait {
                // get list items out of store
                let items: [MyObject]
                do {
                    try items = context.fetch(MyObject.getListItemFetchRequest())
                } catch {
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }
                
                // reorder items
                items.enumerated().forEach { index, item in
                    if item.item?.index != index {
                        item.item?.index  = index
                    }
                }
                
                // save if we need to save
                if context.hasChanges {
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    lazy var operationQueue: OperationQueue = {
       var queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        return queue
    }()
    
}
```

But after this everything works exactly like before. Is there something I'm missing or another way to achieve what I need?

Comment: There are (at least) two ways: 1) Mirror the index in `MyObject` 2) Create an extra Core Data entity. A custom class declared as `transformable` is bad practice anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. May I ask you why? I just started with core data and I have a class with ui images, string arrays  and another class. I didn't know what else to do... Thank you so much again @vadian

Comment: Because serializing classes to `Data` can be pretty expensive, more expensive than using entities and relationships

Comment: Got it, I'll totally revisit my project. I think I already found my way. Thank you again for your precious help @vadian